# error installing gruntjs from ivy

Tags: ant, gruntjs, npm

I'm getting error when trying to install gruntjs with ivy tool.
In my build.xml there is:

```
<echo message="installing gruntjs support..." />
<get src="http://ivy.iwin.com/gruntjs-build.xml" dest="${gruntjs.build.file}" usetimestamp="true" />
<import file="${gruntjs.build.file}" />
```

This gruntjs-build.xml installs nodejs:

```
<echo message="installing nodejs support..." />
<get src="http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml" dest="${nodejs.build.file}" usetimestamp="true" />
<import file="${nodejs.build.file}" />
```

And when the "gruntjs.install" taks is called, i'm getting the following error:

```
gruntjs.install:
     [exec] npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: %3E
     [exec] npm ERR! 404
     [exec] npm ERR! 404 '%3E' is not in the npm registry.
     [exec] npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
     [exec] npm ERR! 404
     [exec] npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
     [exec] npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
     [exec]
     [exec] npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
     [exec] npm ERR! command "c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\\\node.exe" "c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli" "--prefix" "c:\\project-dir/nodejs-lib" ">" "_tempfile.out" "2>&1"
     [exec] npm ERR! cwd c:\project-dir
     [exec] npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
     [exec] npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.12
     [exec] npm ERR! code E404
     [exec] npmThe system cannot find the file specified.
     [exec] Could Not Find c:\project-dir\_tempfile.out
```

If i run "touch _tempfile.out", it continues with other "Some file is not in npm registry". And i think the matter is in how nodejs was installed.
I tried to uninstall nodejs, and run it from administrative console, but with same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the entire command line is being passed to `npm`, including the character `>` which `npm` is escaping as %3E.

Something is invoking `npm` with the arguments `"c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\\\node.exe" "c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli" "--prefix" "c:\\project-dir/nodejs-lib" ">" "_tempfile.out" "2>&1"`

So instead of output and stderr being redirected to `_tempfile.out`, `npm` thinks you want to install module named `">" "_tempfile.out" "2>&1"`

Whatever is invoking `npm` (ivy? maven? some other tool?) probably has an out-of-band way to specify the output redirection, so try poking around in your config files to see where `"_tempfile.out"` is specified and see if you can get `node` to run with just this command-line:

`"c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\\\node.exe" "c:\\project-dir\\nodejs-lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli" "--prefix" "c:\\project-dir/nodejs-lib"`

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your issue. The remote ANT build file is no longer available.
I also don't understand why you consider this an ivy question.

I would submit that you should be calling the NPM tool directory from your build. See the installation docs for Grunt:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

## Example

Attempt to recreate this question fails as follows:

```
build:
     [echo] installing nodejs support...
      [get] Getting: http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml
      [get] To: /home/mark/tmp/build.xml.tmp
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml
      [get] Error opening connection java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml
      [get] Can't get http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml to /home/mark/tmp/build.xml.tmp
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <property name="nodejs.build.file" location="build.xml.tmp"/>

  <target name="build">
    <echo message="installing nodejs support..." />
    <get src="http://ivy.iwin.com/nodejs-build.xml" dest="${nodejs.build.file}" usetimestamp="true" />
    <import file="${nodejs.build.file}" />
  </target>

</project>
```